# Create matrix containing the set of vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let `V` be the matrix `16*7`  and `r` a vector of dimension `1*7`. We have a total of `16` vectors `r`.

I want to create the matrix `V` containing the set of vector `r`, ordered by line by line.

Comment: Why do you have 16 `r` vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
V = [r1; r2; r3; r4; r5; r6; r7];
```

As this seems to be a basic question to me, having a look at the [Getting Started](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) tutorial may be useful for you.

**Example**

For the following input

```
r1 = 1*ones(1, 7);
r2 = 2*ones(1, 7);
r3 = 3*ones(1, 7);
r4 = 4*ones(1, 7); 
r5 = 5*ones(1, 7); 
r6 = 6*ones(1, 7); 
r7 = 7*ones(1, 7);
```

will this generate the following output:

```
V =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
     6     6     6     6     6     6     6
     7     7     7     7     7     7     7
```

Comment: You are welcome, but I definitely encourage you to look at the tutorial.